# Immoscrapy Returns No Results When Searching For Apartment Listings

Tags: web-scraping

I have installed [immoscrapy](https://github.com/venthur/immoscrapy) and was hoping to use it to scrape apartment listings in Berlin, Germany, however, none of the parameters I enter returns any search results.

searching for:

```
immoscrapy buy-apartment --country de --region berlin --price 100000-800000 --numberofrooms 5-
```

returns:

```
2022-11-04 10:28:48,513 INFO numexpr.utils NumExpr defaulting to 8 threads.
2022-11-04 10:28:48,732 INFO immoscrapy.immoscrapy Using URL: https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/de/berlin/wohnung-kaufen?sorting=2&price=100000-800000&numberofrooms=5-
2022-11-04 10:28:48,732 DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.immobilienscout24.de:443
2022-11-04 10:28:48,868 DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool https://www.immobilienscout24.de:443 "POST /Suche/de/berlin/wohnung-kaufen?sorting=2&price=100000-800000&numberofrooms=5- HTTP/1.1" 204 0
2022-11-04 10:28:48,868 WARNING immoscrapy.immoscrapy Search returned 0 results.
No results.
```

I have tried to change the search parameters, but it did not help.

Is this because of the crawler blocker and "I am not a robot" authentification they have on their website?
Are there other packages that work? I would like to use the data for a school project and do some machine learning with it. Sorry if my question is too basic, I am very new to coding.